# How do I install NSIS plugins?

Tags: plugins, nsis

I am trying to make an installer using NSIS (I'm new to it). My installer requires the use of the INetC plugin, and while installing I tried both the wiki download and [this repo](https://github.com/DigitalMediaServer/NSIS-INetC-plugin/releases/tag/v1.0.5.7) to no avail.

The INetC plugin does not contain an includable `.nsh` file.

I searched SO and NSIS forums, which all said to put the `.dll` files into their respective `x86-ansi` and `x86-unicode` folders. I did that, but the plugin had no effect.

When doing `makensis /v4` for the logs (which some old SO posts suggested), there was no INetC plugin listed.

I also tried using `!addplugindir` with the flags for each respective dll folder, but that also did not work.

Can someone help me figure out what I need to do?

Edit: NSIS version is 3.08 btw if that helps

Comment: Not all plug-ins have a .nsh. makensis /v4 will tell you where your plug-in directory is...

Answer (score -1):

To "install" plugin simply copy the .dll file into appropriate **x86-ansi / x86-unicode** folder.

Make sure you are copying **Unicode** build of plugin into **x86-unicode** folder and **ANSI** build of plugin into **x86-ansi** folder.

That is all, *there are no .nsh files or anything*.

Use **SetUnicode true / false** to switch between Unicode/Ansi installer.